# Moving a 40Gb file truncates it to 5Gb

Tags: linux, backup

I want to move a file called `cpmbackup.tar.gz` from the folder `/home/username` to `/home/username/public_html` (and afterwards change the permission to 644 so it can be downloaded from another server with ssh `wget URL.tar.gz`).

**But**, after I move this file to `public_html`, **only** 5 or 6 gig of the 40Gig file have been moved.

I have ssh and Cpanel

Comment: Are you saying you need to transfer it to another server? Or on the same system? And it's failing after transferring only 5 or 6 gig, or...?

Comment: no bart , i problem for move file from /home/username/ to home/username/public_html .

Comment: because i need one link for download this file back from another server

Comment: And it transfers 6 gig then errors out?

Comment: Does it complete the transfer without error, or does it give you an error message?  What command are you using to move the file?

Comment: after moving or copying file use cpanel to public_html ... stopped tranfer without showing error

Comment: Can you post the commands you used to move the file?

Comment: Are /home/username and /home/username/public_html on the same partition? If they are the `mv /home/username/cpmbackup.tar.gz /home/username/public_html/cpmbackup.tar.gz` command should happen pretty quick. If you are copying the data then make sure you are not running out of diskspace or inodes with `df -h` and `df -i`

Comment: no mark , i have use copy button  from cpanel

Comment: Then, try `mv`.

Comment: digitaladdictions & Shane Madden  yes  :) 
this problem for move use Cpanel , i with ssh mv very very easy & fast transit this file (+40Gig) 
TanX From All (have Good Time), ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment about using the copy command in cpanel I would suggest you are probably running out of diskspace.

You mentioned you do have ssh access available and I an unfamiliar with cpanel so if you can ssh into the server you should check your diskspace with the following command:

```
df -h
```

There is also a possibility that you are running out of inodes although unlikely since it is a single tar file.

```
df -i
```

If you have ssh access you will be much better off moving the file instead of trying to copy it.

```
mv /home/username/cpmbackup.tar.gz /home/username/public_html/cpmbackup.tar.gz
```

This will happen almost instantaneously instead of waiting and hour or more for it to copy. It also will not use up any additional disk space.

Comment: "This will happen almost instantaneously instead of waiting and hour or more for it to copy" - Assuming that the file's source and destination are on the same filesystem.